# Use inventory module in custom module in odoo 10

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-10

I'm new to Odoo. I have two fields call parts and location. I need to take the relevant products from inventory. How can I do that in xml and python.
Here is my code,

```
class SO_Parts(models.Model):
_name = 'my_so_parts'

so_p_id = fields.Many2one('my_depots_so',string='Add Service Order Part', invisible='1')
created_date = fields.Date('Date Created',default=date.today(),readonly=True)
so_part_type = [
                ('r_r','Remove/Repair'),('add','Add'),('r_s','Remove/Scrap'),('r_b','Remove/Bench')
                ]
so_part_t = fields.Selection(so_part_type,'Type',default ='add', required='1')
so_part_product = fields.Char('Product')
so_part_description = fields.Char('Description')
so_part_sno = fields.Char('Serial No:')
so_part_qty = fields.Integer('Quantity')
so_part_stype = [
           ('stockable','Stockable'),('consumable','Consumable')
        ]
so_ps_type = fields.Selection(so_part_stype,'Stock Type',default ='stockable', required='1')
so_part_source = [
    ('mystock','MS'),('shop','Shop')
]
so_psource = fields.Selection(so_part_source,'Source',default ='toweriq', required='1')
bo_sequence = fields.Char('BO Number', readonly=True)
bo_status = [
    ('new', 'New')]
bo_status = fields.Selection(bo_status, 'Status', default='new')
```

I need to do this using Inventory module.. Here I do this without using Inventory module

Comment: You question is unclear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to do this process combining the inventory module

Answer (score 0):

you can use `product.product` as many to one field. for so_part_product = fields.Char('Product') replace it with

```
so_part_product = fields.Many2one('product.product',string='Product')
```

Thank you